# Rank of Elliptic Curves

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves

Recently, I have heard of some heuristics that would suggest that the rank of elliptic curves are bounded (specifically in the congruent number family). I always though that the best way to prove something about the rank of an elliptic curve is to look at the rank of the 2-Selmer group. Indeed, I was able to find a reference that says that the rank in the congruent number family of elliptic curves is bounded by the 2-Selmer rank.

Clearly it is not known that the 2-Selmer rank is bounded, but is it known that it is unbounded in the congruent number family? What about in general? Is this equivalent to asking if the rank of elliptic curves is unbounded?

I would appreciate any answers or references.

Comment: when you say **Clearly it is not known that the 2-Selmer rank is bounded, but is it known that it is unbounded in the congruent number family?** do you have a reference?

Comment: Well if it is known that the 2-Selmer rank is bounded, then that would imply that the rank of elliptic curves is bounded, at least in the case I am talking about.

Comment: as a service to other readers - especially me - please define the 2-Selmber rank in your question?  And I don't know what you mean by "congruent number family".

Comment: On MO http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177897/rank-of-elliptic-curves

Answer (score 2):

This is a subject I am interested in, but I have trouble parsing through the definitions.

Notes: **[Selmer-Group, Tate-Shafarevich Group and the Weak Mordell-Weil Theorem](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~roblot/ihp/weakmw.pdf)** (Poonen)

Understanding the Selmer Group of Elliptic Curves involves the Tate-Shafarevich Group and some Group Cohomology.

Notes: **[Average Rank of Elliptic Curves](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/research/BSD2011/bsd2011-Bhargava.pdf)** (Bhargava)

Paper: **[Heuristics on Class Groups and on Tate-Shafarevich Groups: the Magic of the Cohen-Lenstra Heuristics](http://delaunay.perso.math.cnrs.fr/heuristics_2.pdf)** (Delaunay)